# Add custom header to email

Tags: linux, postfix, email-server

I have a question here that I'm a bit lost on, I need to create an email server with postfix, sendmail or something like that, but with something very specific, the idea is that an application in Ruby on Rails can add a specific header for that email, just like Google does with its emails by adding the X-EnvId:
Does anyone know if there is a way to do this with an opensource email server like postfix or sendmail? I had seen that Postfix can be added by changing /etc/postfix/addheader, but my question is how it would work for an email client to pass this parameter to the server.
If anyone knows how to go about this and help me, I would be very grateful.

Comment: The typical interface (open source) mailservers add to allow  external modules to  interact with messages is the [milter interface/API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milter) which are usually used to manage incoming e-mail but also will work for outgoing e-mail messages (like for instance OpenDKIM signing of messages)

Comment: But an application can always set any header when it's generating the message, so if your application can set a parameter, it can  also set a header. Your application is not limited to only setting `From:`  , `Subject:` and `Date:`  headers, you should be able to set any header, `X-I-am-a-Teapot: false`